# Please help data from web form not showing up in mysql table

Tags: mysql

HI this is a form handler for my web form after submitting the web form without any error, am still not able
to see the newly added record in mysql.

Please can any one tell what I have done wrong?

```
<?php
$_POST['id'];
$_POST['fname'];
$_POST['lname'];
$_POST['house_no'];
$_POST['street_name'];
$_POST['postcode']; 
$_POST['email'];
$_POST['tel'];
$_POST['comments'];

     $host = "";
     $user = "";
     $pass = "";
     $data = "moodscontact";
$cxn = mysql_connect($host,$user,$pass) or die('Connection Failed ' . mysql_error($cxn));

mysql_select_db($data);

$query ="
INSERT INTO moodstable(
id,fname,lname,house_no,street_name,postcode,email,tel,comments)
VALUES
(null'$fname','$lname','$house_no','$street_name','$postcode','$email','$tel','$comments')";

if(isset ($_POST['submit'])){
print 'Query succeeded';
}
else 
{
die('Submission failed ' . mysql_error());
    }

mysql_close($cxn);
?>
```

Comment: A comma is missing at `VALUES
(null'$fname',`.

Answer (score 0):

missing , in the insert query

```
$query ="
INSERT INTO moodstable(
id,fname,lname,house_no,street_name,postcode,email,tel,comments)
VALUES (NULL,'$fname','$lname','$house_no','$street_name','$postcode',
'$email','$tel','$comments')";
```

better use this query

```
$query ="
INSERT INTO moodstable(
fname,lname,house_no,street_name,postcode,email,tel,comments)
VALUES ('$fname','$lname','$house_no','$street_name','$postcode',
'$email','$tel','$comments')";
```